# Show application name instead of process in warning (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

Sometimes we get a warning like this:

```
2019-... [15138] [Xc0BxiGn2g7j] LOG:  process 15138 still waiting for ShareLock on transaction 274489730 after 1000.107 ms
2019-... [15138] [Xc0BxiGn2g7j] DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: 14625. Wait queue: 15138.
2019-... [15138] [Xc0BxiGn2g7j] CONTEXT:  while deleting tuple (1,32) in relation "foobar"
2019-... [15138] [Xc0BxiGn2g7j] STATEMENT:  DELETE FROM "foobar" WHERE "foobar"."id" IN (2216750)
```

Unfortuantely the process id (in this case `14625`) does not help much.

We set the `application_name` for all connections to PostgreSQL to a unique request-id.

Is there a way to let the above message print out the application name of the process which holds the connection?

Then it would make it much easier to investigate the root cause.

I updated the question, to show that the request-id of the blocked process is already visible to me. I am searching the request-id of process `14625`.

Answer (score 2):

Just include `%p` and `%a` in your `log_line_prefix` and set `log_disconnections = on`.

Then you get the application name and process ID logged whenever a session disconnects. That will enable you to find in the log which application name belongs to which session. This will work unless sessions are in the habit of changing their `application_name`.

For active connections, just examine `pg_stat_activity`.

Comment: This should work. We already include %a and %p in `log_line_prefix`. The hint to `log_disconnections = on` is new and good. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We append request-id, module, action and few other parameters to every SQL thru SET application_name ''; This may not be the best approach, but this makes it easy to see the source of the query in logs, errors, analytics, etc.

Comment: It is correct what you say. We do that, too.

Comment: I think you are adding that per connection while I am suggesting to add it per sql STATEMENT. So the STATEMENT: in your warning would have the request-Id

Comment: I updated the question, to show that the request-id of the blocked process is already visible to me. I am searching the request-id of process 14625.